# matDatepicker inside *ngFor issue

Tags: angular, angular-material, mat-datepicker

Don't know how to name the click function so it picks up which matdatepicker was clicked. Right now, whenever I update one date it also updates the other.

```
<div class="row" *ngFor="let section of dSections; let i = index" >
    <div class="padding-bottom">
        <div class="row padding-bottom">
            <label>Date</label>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="inputContainer">
                <input readonly
                       matInput
                       [(ngModel)]="date"
                       #myDate
                       name="myDate-{{i}}"
                       id="myDate-{{i}}"
                       placeholder="Select Date"
                       [matDatepicker]="myDatePicker"
                       (keypress)="$event.preventDefault()"
                       (dateChange)="convertMomentToDate($event.target.value, i)"
                       (click)="myDatePicker.open()">
                <button #myDatePickerButton id="myDatePickerButton-{{i}}"
                        (click)="myDatePicker.open()">
                    <img src="assets/images/icon-calendar.svg" alt="calendar icon"/>
                </button>
                <mat-datepicker #myDatePicker></mat-datepicker>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Are you trying to have both a button and a click event call the same method?  Or are you trying to have multiple date pickers in the same container?  I don't see your ngFor in this code selection, either.

Comment: Well, you have all of them bound to the same `[(ngModel)]="date"` for one thing, so no matter how many datepickers you have, they are all going to be bound to the same property. And you're not including the entire template here. If there's a date object on whatever is in your `*ngFor` (let's say it's called `item`) first step would be to bind your `ngModel` to something more like `[(ngModel)]="item.date"`.

Comment: You should post your code somewhere because there are several issues with this code.

Answer (score 0):

May be because ngModel is binding to 'date' so this is updating the value for each input  [(ngModel)]="date".

Try changing ngFor so it binds to current item. Assuming objects in dSection array have ‘date’ property:

```
<div *ngFor="let section of dSections;let i = index;">
  <input  name="myDate-{{i}}" [(ngModel)]="dSections[i].date">
```

(Other attributes left out for ease of reading)